# Redirecting to another item in an AJAX request

Tags: mvc, redirect

I am using Sitecore 8.2 with MVC.

I am trying to perform a page redirect, but my code isn't working.

I'm calling an MVC controller action method from JavaScript using a jQuery AJAX call.

The method is hit and the related items are also present in the content tree. But nothing happens. The current page remains and no redirection occurs. Also, there are no errors or messages in the browser console.

#### Controller method:

```
public ActionResult RedirectPage(string currentItemGuid)
{
  Item pageItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(currentItemGuid);

  if (pageItem != null)
  {
    string pageURL = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(pageItem);
    //pageURL = /products/radio
    string newURL = pageURL + "-type";
    //newURL = /products/radio-type. This item is present in the content tree in the same folder structure.
    return Redirect("~" + newURL);
  }
  else
  {
    return new EmptyResult();
  }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {        
  $(".ddlProducts").change(function () {            
    $.ajax({
      url: "api/sitecore/Products/RedirectPage",
      type: "POST",
      data: { currentItemGuid: '{100-100-100}'},
      context: this,
      success: function (data) {                
          console.log("success", data);
      },
      error: function (data) {
          console.log("error", data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What response do you see in the Network tab of Chrome Development Tools?

Comment: no comments in browser console

Comment: Could you please clarify this "this code isn't working"? Do you have redirect to another url or nothing happens or something else?

Comment: @Vlad. I have edited my question. Please check.

Comment: Any what is your js code?

Comment: Please check what response you see in the **Network tab** of Chrome Development Tools. Find the AJAX request in the Network tab, click on it and see what is contained in the response headers.

Comment: It says 200 ok for status, the type is xhr and the initiator there is the url - http:mysite.org/api/sitecore/product/redirectpage - redirect

Comment: try redirect to another page for example on home page

Comment: @Qwerty Is this a WebAPI or an MVC controller? Asking because of the URL starts with `api`.

Comment: This is an mvc controller. Also i tried redirecting to http://www/google.com. That didnt work too:(

Comment: @Qwerty Have you tried debugging the method? It looks like it always goes to the `else` branch. Probably, the item is not found.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko No. I checked that. The pageItem is not null and it hits the `return Redirect` with new url.

Comment: Can you decorate your controller with [AllowAnonymous]? Just to try, I don't know if it helps.

Comment: @Qwerty I have reverted your question to its previous version. By editing it, you had changed its meaning, and hence, the discussion around it and the answer below lost their meaning. If you want to ask a different question, create one, but please don't change the meaning of this question.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that 301/302 redirects are handled by the browser (or more specifically, by the `XMLHttpRequest` object) *transparently*. This means that your `success` handler will be called only when the browser issues a second request and loads the page it was *redirected to*.

So you should not attempt to use redirect response codes in AJAX calls. Instead, I suggest that you return a custom object containing the redirect URL:

```
return Json(new { redirectUrl = someUrl });
```

And then manually redirect using JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/sitecore/Products/RedirectPage",
    type: "POST",
    data: { currentItemGuid: '{100-100-100}'},
    context: this,
    dataType: "json", // this is important
    success: function (data) {                
        if(data.redirectUrl) {
            window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is only working for the first instance. I have a dropdown in both pages and changing the value should redirect to respective pages. When I browse page1 and change the dropdown, it redirects to page2. Then if I change dropdown in page2, it gives an error. When I browse page2 separately and change dropdown, it redirects to page1 fine. What could be causing this. The error is

Comment: `http://mysite.org/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx?item=%2fapi%2fsitecore%2fproducts%2fredirectpage&user=sitecore%5cadmin&site=mysite.org`

Comment: @Qwerty Is this error something you see in the browser? Are you being redirected to `/api/sitecore/Products/RedirectPage`?..

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. Kindly check.

Comment: @Qwerty you will need to debug your JavaScript code and find out where the wrong redirection URL comes from. This is outside of the scope of this thread. If you can't find the problem by yourself, please post a new question. If you elect to do so, please make sure to provide a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).